# how to put iOS app on more country's stores

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app on the iOS app store at the moment, and I've been asked to make it available on more stores. I can't see how I can change this (or even see what stores it is on). I tried adding a new version to see if the option becomes available but I still can't see where I can put it on more stores.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the rights and pricing link for your app in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @MikeW I would argue that iTunes Connect fits into _software tools commonly used by programmers_.

Comment: @cabellicar123 +1. There are more than 1000 questions tagged itunesconnect here.

Comment: Yep thats the one @rmaddy (how did I miss that). Pop that in an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @cabellicar123 yeah nothing came up as I was typing the question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about availability of a product in stores not about programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Log into iTunes Connect. Manage your apps. Choose your app. Click on "Rights and Pricing". There's a link for choosing the countries.